# How to refresh Firebase messaging tokens in service worker

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am building a PWA, with push notifications powered by FCM.

Push notifications work initially, however when my **web app is in the background** (not visible) the Firebase token eventually expires, and there appears to be no way to update the application server with a refreshed device token via the service worker (the only part still running while the app is in the background)

In my NodeJS server logs, I see the following error when I try to send a push notification to an expired token.

`Error: The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons.`

Is there any way to update the application server with a new device token, when it expires while only the service worker is running? Is there any equivalent to `onTokenRefresh` for the service worker?

Notes:

- Firebase JS v4.13.0
- NodeJS v6.14.3

Comment: AFAIK as long as you `onTokenRefresh` -> sync to DB it should be okay.

Comment: `onTokenRefresh` is only available in the window, so it's not possible to run that function while the web app in backgrounded. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/firebase%404.13.0/packages/messaging/src/controllers/controller-interface.ts#L306

Comment: AFAIK the fcm token will not and should not refresh while the web app is just in background.  The fcm token should only be refreshed if the app is reinstalled, or the notification permission was toggled

Comment: Does that mean FCM is not appropriate for push notifications then? It seems odd that I cannot send notifications to a user, due to the token expiring, if they haven't opened the app in a while.
P.s. "A while" seems quite short, only about 12 hours in my tests.

Comment: Try another device, my FCM token are not getting expired unless it's being refreshed and if it is it is only refreshed when it's on foreground and it's being synced.  However, if you can reproduce your issue, submit your issue on github?